# XSl-FO can every content be dynamic?

Tags: xsl-fo

I am trying to create FO file based on XML file which I have Created from my source.

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ORDER_ID></ORDER_ID>
  <LOGO></LOGO>
  <ORDER_DATE></ORDER_DATE>
  <TRIAL_DATE></TRIAL_DATE>
  </ROW>
  </ROWSET>
 </DOCUMENT>
```

Based on above XML, I am linking values to Fields and generating FO file.
Now, problem is when I try to generate PDF it says

> line 148: At least one element required in .(this is HTML Output..PDF was not loading so I tested in HTML)

I am trying to Print Pdf from Oracle apex 5.0
Not a Pro XSL-FO developer so guide me if you can.

XSL-FO Link :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pac1CRPpFTG3OLJzpHRXE0Yh0Xbdk7MoWaQhT88T258/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your question to include the generated FO; without it, there is no way to understand your problem.

Comment: FO file has way to much Code :)

Comment: Provided Xsl-FO doc File :)

Comment: This does not seem to be very much about xsl-fo, maybe it would be better tagged (also) [oracle-apex] or [oracle-apex-5]?

Comment: yes it is about xsl-fo.
Why i am so sure : Pdf was rendering correctly in apex oracle if i choose static Image but when i select Dynamic image from XML file then it was giving me error.
Reason : i did not change settings for image as shown in below Image.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
[image: XSL-FO image]

Change Image Type and Constant and it worked.
Due to my lake of knowledge of FO tool i did not change this as per my need :)